# How to have Python convert a text file into a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python

I'm given a text file that looks like this:

```
name 1 2 3 4 
othername 5 6 7 8 
...
```

How do I get Python to find the names in the lines, turn them into keys as part of a dictionary, then the following numbers into a list corresponding to those keys?

Comment: sounds like pandas :-)

Comment: What have you tried so far? `data = {row[0]:row[1:] for row in (line.strip().split() for line in open(filename))}` may do the trick

Comment: A few suggestions to improve your question (may explain downvotes & close votes). You might show your expected output explicitly and also its a good idea to show what you tried. People will often correct something you did wrong, but not write new code from scratch for you.

Comment: Your expected output might look like. `{'name': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'othername': [5, 6, 7, 8]} ` ?

Comment: Did one of the solutions below help? Feel free to accept one if it did (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split()
        d[parts[0]] = parts[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.split` with unpacking to first split each line at `\s` and iterate over the result to create the list of integers for each key:

```
import re
data = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in open('filename.txt')]
final_data = {a:list(map(int, b)) for a, *b in data}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way using `csv` module and a dictionary comprehension:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO

scsv = """name 1 2 3 4
othername 5 6 7 8
"""

# replace StringIO(scsv) with 'file.csv'
reader = csv.reader(StringIO(scsv), delimiter=' ')

# iterate items of reader
d = {x: list(map(int, y)) for x, *y in reader}

print(d)

{'name': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'othername': [5, 6, 7, 8]}
```